# OpenCV Mat object - get data length

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV, I'm able to capture frames using VideoCapture in C++, however, when I try to get the data from a frame and calculate length, it just returns me 0.

Below is my sample code:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
for(;;) {
  Mat frame;
  cap >> frame;
  int length = strlen((char*) frame.data); // returns 0
}
```

As I mentioned above that if I save the frame in a PNG file, I can actually see the image so I'm not able to understand why the data length is coming out to be zero.

Any clue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of Matrix OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028193/size-of-matrix-opencv)

Comment: But how do I calculate length of the buffer from the rows and cols info? Moreover, the above code should also work, isn't it?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done OpenCV, but strlen is looking for a null character.  Are you sure `frame.data` doesn't start with a `'\0'` or `0`?  I'm not sure that this is a valid way to tell the buffer size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The strlen method only works on strings, which are arrays of chars terminated by a special character:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/

You have cast a `Mat` type as a `char*`, so it is not a string.

Building on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028193/size-of-matrix-opencv), try:

```
Mat mat;
int rows = mat.rows;
int cols = mat.cols;
int num_el = rows*cols;
int len = num_el*mat.elemSize1();
```

to get the size of one channel in bytes. Also, use `elemSize()` if you want all the channels (i.e. you'll get 3 times the value of `elemSize1()` if the `Mat` is a 3 channel image).

Take a look here for discussion of the various types `Mat` can contain:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-type

Answer (score 14):

You can also do:

```
Mat mat;
int len = mat.total() * mat.elemSize(); // or mat.elemSize1()
```

Comment: This is the preferred answer