# Size of Matrix (image) OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

How to get the dimensions of an image (width and height)?

I just saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14028277/6872717), which shows two methods, and doesn't explicitly state if they are completely equivalent:

> ```
> cv::Mat mat;
> int rows = mat.rows;
> int cols = mat.cols;
>
> cv::Size s = mat.size();
> rows = s.height;
> cols = s.width;
> ```

Are those two methods completely equivalent in every case?

What are the differences if there are any?

---

OpenCV version: 4

Comment: Did you check the documentation? What version of OpenCV do you use?

Comment: I did, and read through the header file `<opencv2/core/mat.hpp>`, but I didn't find a definitive answer.  I've always found opencv documentation very poor.

Comment: For the common case of 2D Mat, you get the same numbers. In case of more than 2 dimensions, accessing `rows` and `cols` directly will give you -1 for each, whereas calling the () operator on the `size` member will cause an assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods are exactly the same. I believe these functions exist for convenience since there are several cases where each method is useful.

For example, to create a new `cv::Mat` of the same size as another, its more convenient to write and easier to read

```
cv::Mat new_mat = cv::Mat(old_mat.size(), old_mat.type())
```

than

```
cv::Mat new_mat = cv::Mat(old_mat.rows, old_mat.cols, old_mat.type()
```

Also, fewer function calls I believe. And it's more convenient to use and easier to read with fewer function calls

```
for(int i=0; i<old_mat.rows; i++)
   for(int j=0; l< old_mat.cols; j++)
```

than

```
for(int i=0; i<old_mat.size().width; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<old_mat.size().height; j++)
```